# Returning ID with information MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql  = 'SELECT `name`, `course`, `id` FROM `teacher`';
$rows = $mysql_conn->fetch_array($sql);
foreach($rows as $record) {
    $search_results[$record['name']] = $record['course'];
}

foreach($search_results as $teacher=>$string_courses){
    $array_courses = explode('-',$string_courses);
    $search_results[$teacher] = $array_courses;
}

foreach($search_results as $teacher=>$courses){
    foreach($courses as $period => $course){
        if($course == $id) {
            $name               = explode(',', $teacher);
            $results[$period][] = '<a href="?page=teacher&id='.ID HERE.'">'.$name[0].'<br />'.$name[1].'</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Where it says ID HERE, I want the ID returned for each teacher inserted there but I do not know how to insert it so that it passes through.

Answer (score 2):

You're building your array in a weird way, using `$record['name']` as a key, change that to `$record['id']` and you have a better start.

Comment: The course gets the teachers by refering to the arrays index. I need to have somewhere in there a spot of the ID to sit because will only be used to link back to a different page.

Comment: Without looking too deep at the code, it seems you're not using the mysql_fetch_array in an optimal way. By default, is collects the fields both as numeric AND associated array. Try to build your RS (first loop), and then request the data by $rs[$recNr][$fieldName]. Or am I overlooking something in your requirements?

Comment: The table is very technical, requires parsing to retrieve the data.

I need to pass an ID along with the array up to the end point where it is referenced in a link.

Comment: ok, I see your string maninpulation needs. However, it's unclear what ID we're talking about. From the top sql? (And you're not looping ->fetch_array(), is that correct?). Instead of redefining $search_results at row7, use another variable and track back to original search_results. Your code looks like excerpts and could use some commenting...

Comment: `$sql  = 'SELECT `name`, `course`, `id` FROM `teacher`';`

The ID inside of the code above is what I need to pass through, the fetch does not loop. It passes all values through then stores it to an array which is what you see. (Very efficient)

Comment: Ah, you're using a class, mysql_conn... Without knowing how your array is built up like, I'm afraid I can't help you. I you need further help, I'd suggest you add comments to your code